# How is voltage divided between two reverse-biased ideal diodes?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, kirchhoffs-laws, circuit-theory, ideal

Suppose we have two identical *ideal* diodes (without any resistance or voltage drop). We connect these two diodes in series, in the same direction, and reverse-bias them with voltage V. Now we have two series reverse-biased ideal diodes. There isn't any other element in the circuit.

What is the voltage value at the node between the diodes? Maybe one would say V/2 because of the symmetry, but any answer between 0 and V cannot be refuted. A reverse-biased diode can (ideally) have any voltage.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to EE.SE! I think your question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320847/voltage-of-reverse-biased-series-diodes).  Please check it out and clarify if you're asking something else.

Comment: The Voltage depends more on the capacitance of the diode at some bias and then it becomes a capacitance divider until the leakage takes over to become a resistance divider. But then the diode with the higher capacitance tends to have the lower leakage resistance, so it may not shift in the opposite direction. Now what is the time constant of the drift in the centre?

Comment: Imagine two 1N4148 with 20nA @ Vr=20V yet 5uA at -75V
and C=4pF @ 0V yet  C= 0.1pF at -20V that varies on log scale.  What is the centre drift T=RC with 2 same in series reversed at 40V?

Comment: Yet actually the one with the lower Rs in the forward direction like the 1N4448 that has 10x the current @ 1V over the 1N4148 yet only 1/2 the capacitance at 0V.  So if you put a 1N4148 in series with a 1N4448, with 40V reverse, What is the node voltage and how long does it take for T? But they have identical reverse current leakage.

Comment: @Sparky256 this is not a duplicate of that question. That is an engineering real world question and diodes are not ideal there. This is an abstract mathematical situation solution of which was interesting to me. I wanted an answer like those of Dennis Ernst.

Answer (score 4):

In case of *ideal* diodes you can see them as open switches if reverse biased, since there is no leaking current and so on.
So there is no voltage at this point. Its floating.

Comment: I edited your answer because we need to keep them in the realm of science. Adding emotional content should be avoided. Stern but explained warnings to those working with deadly voltages (surge generators, large high-voltage capacitors, etc) are ok.

Comment: So how do you satisfy KVL?

Comment: Because reverse biased ideal diode is an open switch, there is no complete circuit and KVL doesn't apply.

Comment: @TemeV KVL does apply. The junction of the diodes is floating, say, \$v\$ volts. Therefore KVL gives \$V= (V-v)+(v-0)\$

Comment: @Chu KVL states literally "The directed sum of the potential differences (voltages) around any closed loop is zero." (From Wikipedia) When there is an open switch, there is no closed loop. If you were to measure that voltage between two open switches, what result will you get? What if you first measure from V to v and then v to 0, will you get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal diodes will be two open circuits, hence the junction of the diodes is floating at, say, a random \$\small v\$ volts. Therefore KVL gives: \$\small V=(V−v)+(v−0)\$, where \$\small V\$ is the voltage across the series combination.

Comment: It is not possible to define voltage between the two open switches. Voltage between two points is defined as the work needed per unit of charge to move a test charge between the two points. 1 volt = 1 joule (of work) per 1 coulomb (of charge). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage As there is no path to move the charge (circuit is open) the amount of work needed to move it is, I guess, infinite. So voltage would also be infinite.

Comment: @TemeV Interesting point. Can an isolated conductor have an instantaneous voltage relative to an arbitrary ground reference? I guess the conductor can acquire a charge, and that charge would need work to move it to the arbitrary ground. Hence it has a voltage.

Comment: If there is a path for the charge, then yes there is a voltage. This is of course always the case in reality, because perfect insulators don't exist. There is always some parasitic impedance where the charge can travel given enough work. But this topic is about ideal components.

Comment: @TemeV Yes, ideal components but not necessarily ideal environment. A random ideal conductor will acquire noise signals.

Comment: There is no point on assuming ideal components if the environment is not also assumed ideal.

Comment: @TemeV There is also no point in asking about non-idealities in circuits but demanding we use ideal components. (ex: What happens if I put two voltage sources is parallel. Ideal components only!!!) Of course a floating conductor has a voltage relative to ground. It is related to the charge on the conductor and its capacitance. You are thinking too narrowly in your first comment. Of course there is a path to get the charge there. You can move an electron through the air, or vacuum, or whatever medium this circuit is in.

Comment: @Matt I guess this is a matter of opinion. In my opinion if one asks about ideal components, the whole environment is also assumed ideal, unless mentioned otherwise. In an ideal insulator no electrons move, how else would it be ideal. "There is also no point in asking about non-idealities in circuits but demanding we use ideal components." Yes, there is no point, and I don't see that anyone did this. Answer to the original question is that the voltage can't be defined. Any attempt to define the voltage requires the non-idealities to be there, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: Good answer doesn't always have to be a number. E.g. answer to the the ideal voltage sources in parallel is that "it can't be defined". Was that a good question? Maybe not. Will the answer please the asker? Maybe not. What non-idealities shall we assume to get some number as an answer? Well, the asker of the original question must answer to that. Was there a point on asking this? The answer and following discussion did likely enlighten the asker, so yes there was a point.

Comment: @TemeV I think the answer to this question is going to rely heavily on the assumptions that go into the ideal models and how we chose to interpret them. Is the value at that node undefined? Or can it take on any value that doesn't cause the diodes to become forward biased? If you are talking about ideal circuit elements, I think you have to throw out any arguments based in physics since they model reality and ideal circuit elements obviously depart from reality. Which is why I think its better to answer the question asked, but add an answer that is a bit more based in reality.

Comment: @Matt Well my first point actually was, that you have to throw out KVL because the loop isn't closed. This was in the comments of the other answer. I agree on adding some reality. Sparky256's answer is correct for the original question, but for educational purposes it is good to augment the answer with a circuit that has a bit more reality. But, then you have to specify what parts of the reality you added. E.g. you have to define that the insulators are non-ideal to get the KVL to work like in Chu's answer.

Comment: This discussion is going off topic by the way, maybe this should be moved to meta